# create-react-app MaterialUI Error: Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to do Create-react-app and use Material UI, but I get a Hooks Error.

Am I missing something else?

This is an error statement.

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

I did the following.

```
$ npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript

$ npm install @mui/material

$ npm install @mui/icons-material
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "muitest",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.37",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import GitHubIcon from '@mui/icons-material/GitHub';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <GitHubIcon />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/](http://react-typescript)
[https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui](http://add%20mui%20to%20typescript%20and%20react)

please go through this both link, u need to add few packages then it will work.

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled @types/material-ui
```

for typescript we need to install few package @types packages.

[image: as shown its working for me]